# Using delay when mapping over a list in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga to send a bunch of requests to the server. What I have a map of names to be sent to the server. But I want to wait for 5 seconds before sending each name

```
function* sendAllNames() {
  const nameData = ['foo','bar']
  yield nameData
    .map(function*(name) {
      yield delay(5000);
      yield fork(
        sendNameRequest,
        {
          requestType: postRequest,
        },
        {
          name,
        },
      );
    });
}
```

The problem is that the initial name waits for 5 seconds before being sent, but there's no delay in sending the next one. Could I force a 5-second delay for all requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` doesn't know to do anything special with generator functions. Map will call the generator with each element of the array, and then synchronously returns an array with the iterators it got.

Instead, i'd recommend using a `for ... in` loop:

```
function* sendAllNames() {
  const nameData = ['foo','bar'];
  for (const name in nameData) {
    yield delay(5000);
    yield fork(
      sendNameRequest,
      { requestType: postRequest },
      { name },
    );
  }
}
```